# Does Azure Cognitive Services support (detect and compare) Handwritten Signatures and Stamps from two images?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services, azure-machine-learning-service

Is there a way using Azure Cognitive Services to compare two images each containing handwritten 
signatures or stamps to come back with  a confidence level that the signatures in the scanned 
images are similar or that the stamp is the right stamp?

Hint:

1- We are "not" looking for a solution to convert printed or handwritten text in an 
image to a machine readable format (like OCR for example)

2- We want to compare two images together and come back with a confidence level that they 
are similar. For example, in Face recognition the Face API is able to take two different 
images of the face of a person and can identify it is the same person. The only difference 
in our scenario is instead of dealing with Faces we want to deal with Handwritten 
Signatures and Stamps.

Comment: Have you found a solution using Azure on signature comparision / verification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an available feature on Azure Cognitive Search. You'll need to work with some computer vision AI model.

Comment: What do you mean by adding "cognitive services" in parenthesis? There is nothing in Microsoft Cognitive Services which is doing something similar to the request

Comment: @NicolasR there's nothing ready to use, but it can be done using Custom Vision, which is part of Cognitive Services

Comment: Ok, but based on my experience with Custom vision, I don't think it will do the job. Custom Vision is made for Classification or Object detection, but real image similarities is another process. Maybe Custom Vision could be used to detect the stamp / signature zone, but that's the only thing it could do